# Convert Activity to Fragment which use Database and Adapter class

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm loading json file from online and saving it on Sqlite such that when app is offline...Then still user will be able to see the data.
It works fine in MainActivity.

But when I try to covert it into  fragment, I'm getting errors of Fragment cannot be cast in to FlowerAdapter$FlowerClickListener

Here is the error file
[image]

My Fragment name is nepali.

Here is the Mainactivity

```html
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FlowerAdapter.FlowerClickListener, FlowerFetchListener {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RestManager mManager;
    private FlowerAdapter mFlowerAdapter;
    private FlowerDatabase mDatabase;
    private Button mReload;
    private ProgressDialog mDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        configViews();

        mManager = new RestManager();
        mDatabase = new FlowerDatabase(this);

        loadFlowerFeed();

        mReload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                loadFlowerFeed();
            }
        });
    }

    private void loadFlowerFeed() {

        mDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        mDialog.setMessage("Loading Flower Data...");
        mDialog.setCancelable(true);
        mDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        mDialog.setIndeterminate(true);

        mFlowerAdapter.reset();

        mDialog.show();

        if (getNetworkAvailability()) {
            getFeed();
        } else {
            getFeedFromDatabase();
        }
    }

    private void getFeedFromDatabase() {
        mDatabase.fetchFlowers(this);
    }

    private void configViews() {
        mReload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reload);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.setRecycledViewPool(new RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool());
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));

        mFlowerAdapter = new FlowerAdapter(this);

        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mFlowerAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(int position) {

    }

    public void getFeed() {

        Call<List<Flower>> listCall = mManager.getFlowerService().getAllFlowers();
        listCall.enqueue(new Callback<List<Flower>>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Flower>> call, Response<List<Flower>> response) {

                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    List<Flower> flowerList = response.body();

                    for (int i = 0; i < flowerList.size(); i++) {
                        Flower flower = flowerList.get(i);

                        SaveIntoDatabase task = new SaveIntoDatabase();
                        task.execute(flower);

                        mFlowerAdapter.addFlower(flower);
                    }
                } else {
                    int sc = response.code();
                    switch (sc) {
                        case 400:
                            Log.e("Error 400", "Bad Request");
                            break;
                        case 404:
                            Log.e("Error 404", "Not Found");
                            break;
                        default:
                            Log.e("Error", "Generic Error");
                    }
                }
                mDialog.dismiss();

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Flower>> call, Throwable t) {
                mDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }




        });
    }

    public boolean getNetworkAvailability() {
        return Utils.isNetworkAvailable(getApplicationContext());
    }

    @Override
    public void onDeliverAllFlowers(List<Flower> flowers) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onDeliverFlower(Flower flower) {
        mFlowerAdapter.addFlower(flower);
    }

    @Override
    public void onHideDialog() {
        mDialog.dismiss();
    }

    public class SaveIntoDatabase extends AsyncTask<Flower, Void, Void> {


        private final String TAG = SaveIntoDatabase.class.getSimpleName();

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Flower... params) {

            Flower flower = params[0];

            try {


            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

and FlowerDatabase class is

```html
public class FlowerDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String TAG = FlowerDatabase.class.getSimpleName();

    public FlowerDatabase(Context context) {
        super(context, Constants.DATABASE.DB_NAME, null, Constants.DATABASE.DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        try {
            db.execSQL(Constants.DATABASE.CREATE_TABLE_QUERY);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Log.d(TAG, ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL(Constants.DATABASE.DROP_QUERY);
        this.onCreate(db);
    }

    public void addFlower(Flower flower) {

        Log.d(TAG, "Values Got " + flower.getName());

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(Constants.DATABASE.PRODUCT_ID, flower.getProductId());
        values.put(Constants.DATABASE.CATEGORY, flower.getCategory());
        values.put(Constants.DATABASE.PRICE, Double.toString(flower.getPrice()));
        values.put(Constants.DATABASE.INSTRUCTIONS, flower.getInstructions());
        values.put(Constants.DATABASE.NAME, flower.getName());
        try {
            db.insert(Constants.DATABASE.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        db.close();
    }

    public void fetchFlowers(FlowerFetchListener listener) {
        FlowerFetcher fetcher = new FlowerFetcher(listener, this.getWritableDatabase());
        fetcher.start();
    }

    public class FlowerFetcher extends Thread {

        private final FlowerFetchListener mListener;
        private final SQLiteDatabase mDb;

        public FlowerFetcher(FlowerFetchListener listener, SQLiteDatabase db) {
            mListener = listener;
            mDb = db;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Cursor cursor = mDb.rawQuery(Constants.DATABASE.GET_FLOWERS_QUERY, null);

            final List<Flower> flowerList = new ArrayList<>();

            if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {

                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        Flower flower = new Flower();
                        flower.setFromDatabase(true);
                        flower.setName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.DATABASE.NAME)));

                        flower.setPrice(Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.DATABASE.PRICE))));
                        flower.setInstructions(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.DATABASE.INSTRUCTIONS)));
                        flower.setCategory(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.DATABASE.CATEGORY)));
                        flower.setProductId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.DATABASE.PRODUCT_ID))));

                        flowerList.add(flower);
                        publishFlower(flower);

                    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                }
            }
            Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mListener.onDeliverAllFlowers(flowerList);
                    mListener.onHideDialog();
                }
            });
        }

        public void publishFlower(final Flower flower) {
            Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mListener.onDeliverFlower(flower);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

and FlowerAdapter Class is

```html
public class FlowerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FlowerAdapter.Holder> {

    private static final String TAG = FlowerAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
    private final FlowerClickListener mListener;
    private List<Flower> mFlowers;

    public FlowerAdapter(FlowerClickListener listener) {
        mFlowers = new ArrayList<>();
        mListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public Holder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View row = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_item, null, false);
        return new Holder(row);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(Holder holder, int position) {

        Flower currFlower = mFlowers.get(position);

        holder.mName.setText(currFlower.getName());
        holder.minstruction.setText(currFlower.getInstructions());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mFlowers.size();
    }

    public void addFlower(Flower flower) {
        mFlowers.add(flower);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    /**
     * @param position
     * @return
     */
    public Flower getSelectedFlower(int position) {
        return mFlowers.get(position);
    }

    public void reset() {
        mFlowers.clear();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        private TextView mName, minstruction;

        public Holder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.flowerName);
            minstruction = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.flowerPrice);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mListener.onClick(getLayoutPosition());
        }
    }

    public interface FlowerClickListener {

        void onClick(int position);
    }
}
```

My fragment class is that I try   to convert above Mainactivity code into Frament class is

```html
public class nepali extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = nepali.class.getSimpleName();
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RestManager mManager;
    private FlowerAdapter mFlowerAdapter;
    private FlowerDatabase mDatabase;
    private Button mReload;
    private ProgressDialog mDialog;
    View view;
   

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_data, container, false);
     configViews();

          mManager = new RestManager();
        mDatabase = new FlowerDatabase(getActivity());

        loadFlowerFeed();

        mReload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                loadFlowerFeed();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    private void loadFlowerFeed() {

        mDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        mDialog.setMessage("Loading Flower Data...");
        mDialog.setCancelable(true);
        mDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        mDialog.setIndeterminate(true);

        mFlowerAdapter.reset();

        mDialog.show();

        if (getNetworkAvailability()) {
            getFeed();
        } else {
            getFeedFromDatabase();
        }
    }

 private void getFeedFromDatabase() {
        mDatabase.fetchFlowers(this);
    }
    private void configViews() {
        mReload = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.reload);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)  view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.setRecycledViewPool(new RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool());
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));

     mFlowerAdapter = new FlowerAdapter((FlowerAdapter.FlowerClickListener) this);;

        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mFlowerAdapter);
    }



    public void getFeed() {

        Call<List<Flower>> listCall = mManager.getFlowerService().getAllFlowers();
        listCall.enqueue(new Callback<List<Flower>>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Flower>> call, Response<List<Flower>> response) {

                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    List<Flower> flowerList = response.body();

                    for (int i = 0; i < flowerList.size(); i++) {
                        Flower flower = flowerList.get(i);

                        SaveIntoDatabase task = new SaveIntoDatabase();
                        task.execute(flower);

                        mFlowerAdapter.addFlower(flower);
                    }
                } else {
                    int sc = response.code();
                    switch (sc) {
                        case 400:
                            Log.e("Error 400", "Bad Request");
                            break;
                        case 404:
                            Log.e("Error 404", "Not Found");
                            break;
                        default:
                            Log.e("Error", "Generic Error");
                    }
                }
                mDialog.dismiss();

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Flower>> call, Throwable t) {
                mDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }




        });
    }

    public boolean getNetworkAvailability() {
        return Utils.isNetworkAvailable(getActivity());
    }




    public void onDeliverFlower(Flower flower) {
        mFlowerAdapter.addFlower(flower);
    }


    public void onHideDialog() {
        mDialog.dismiss();
    }

    public class SaveIntoDatabase extends AsyncTask<Flower, Void, Void> {


        private final String TAG = SaveIntoDatabase.class.getSimpleName();

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Flower... params) {

            Flower flower = params[0];

            try {


            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
            }

            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Lastly the FlowerService  class is

```html
public interface FlowerService {

    @GET("/routine/first.json")
    Call<List<Flower>> getAllFlowers();
}
```

and FlowerFetchListener Class is

```html
public interface FlowerFetchListener {

    void onDeliverAllFlowers(List<Flower> flowers);

    void onDeliverFlower(Flower flower);

    void onHideDialog();
}
```

Please Help....and Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not call db and network from activity or fragment. Try to learn MVVM architecture and use ViewModel to store the data from db or network. You may put a lot of effort making your app work but it will still lead to crashes (especially after you introduce fragment and call db and API from there). You will need to handle your data state during configuration changes. Listen to this talk and start writing clean code https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=5qlIPTDE274

The error you get is because you pass wrong parameter into adapter constructor ‘new FlowerAdapter((FlowerAdapter.FlowerClickListener) this)’. If you want to pass a listener to the adapter you need to pass the class which implements the listener: either activity - then pass getActivity(), or fragment ‘this’ - then make fragment implement implements FlowerAdapter.FlowerClickListener.Be aware that it can be null when fragment is not attached to activity, eg configuration change.

Comment: Thanks I just added  implements FlowerAdapter.FlowerClickListener, FlowerFetchListener into fragment and it worked.